# Setting a process's exit status from a pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, exit-code

I have a process with one "main" thread and several child threads.  Every child thread is in a detached state because the return status is unimportant to the main thread.

To close the program, the main thread requests all other threads stop, then the main thread `pthread_exit`s.  The program then quits when the last child thread quits.

The problem is the exit status of my application is always 0 when terminated in this way.

However, sometimes I want to exit with an error (exit value of 1).  Is there any way I can have the main thread set the exit status flag before it `pthread_exit`s?

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure `main()` exits last, just end it by calling

```
return <exit-value>;
```

instead of calling `pthread_exit()`.

---

Update:

If you cannot make sure `main()` exits last, your program seem to suffers a design flaw.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  But, I can't make sure main exits last because `main()` can't `pthread_join` the other threads because they are in a detached state.